# ValueGenerator factory support in npgsql 3.1

Tags: npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to implement an automatically generated value on ADD, and according to [this example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53858.entity-framework-core-hasvaluegenerator-using-c.aspx) it is pretty straight forward. The problem is that the generator method never gets invoked, so I am wondering if npgsql simply lacks support for this?

Example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
{
 
  entity.Property(e => e.AccountNumber)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .HasValueGenerator<AccountGenerator>();
 
});
```

```
public class AccountGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
  {
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    private string NextAccountNumber()
    {
         .....
         return "some generated string";
    }

    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry) => NextAccountNumber();
```

Answer (score 2):

Npgsql supports value generators just like other EF Core providers - but you'll need to post a fully runnable code sample rather than fragments. The below code works and inserts "some generated string".

```cs
await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

ctx.Customers.Add(new());
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Username=test;Password=test")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(e => e.AccountNumber)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasValueGenerator<AccountGenerator>();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}

public class AccountGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;
    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry) => "some generated string";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed confirmation that this specific feature should work and therefore only posted code fragments. Now that I have your working example I know the problem is not in EF Core. Cheers!

Comment: Always good to post a full code sample (as I did above) - it helps other understand exactly what problem you're running into, and in many cases will allow you to find the issue before even posting.